# Не могу установить Laravel с помощью docker на macOS m1

Tags: laravel, docker, macos

Я еще не очень понимаю, как работает docker, и я не смог найти решение моей проблемы в интернете.

Я всего лишь хотел установить laravel с помощью docker, как написано на официальном сайте laravel.
Но в сейчас в итоге у меня абсолютно не работает докер.

Изначально я вводил команду:
`curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

и затем ввел команду:
`./vendor/bin/sail up`

На что я получал ошибку:

> docker 'compose' is not a docker command

В настройках докера я увидел, что мне нужно обновить докер, но после того, как я нажал на кнопку обновления, кнопка перешла в статус "docker is updating" и зависла на несколько часов.

Я пробовал перезапускать докер и mac, но ничего не помогло, затем я решил удалить докер и скачать его заново.

Теперь нет уведомления о том, что мне нужно обновиться, а версия Docker Desktop - 4.19.0 но при вводе команды
`curl -s "https://laravel.build/polis-test" | bash`

терминал выдает ошибку

> Docker is not running.

Хотя Docker Desktop is running.

Команда:
`docker version`

Выдает:

> command not found: docker

Как мне запустить теперь докер, и затем установить laravel

Comment: Значит у Вас не стоит докер) Или Вы забыли перезапустить консоль

Comment: а как он может не стоять, если статус у докера docker is running?
Я не просто перезапустил консоль, я перезагрузил mac

Answer (score 0):

Потыкав разные кнопки в разделе troubleshout и после очередного раза, когда я нажал на кнопку Quit Docker Desktop, мой докер наконец-то отреагировал, и после перезапуска он запустился как первый раз после установки без каких-либо образов и контейнеров.

После этого две команды, которые я вводил - заработали
Не знаю, что это было.

Если кто-то понял, о чем речь, напишите, пожалуйста